# Bouncing off a circular Boundary with multiple balls?

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas

I am making a game like this :

[image: Smiley Game]

Yellow Smiley has to escape from red smileys, when yellow smiley hits the boundary game is over, when red smileys hit the boundary they should bounce back with the same angle they came, like shown below:

[image: Bounce angle]

Every 10 seconds a new red smiley comes in the big circle, when red smiley hits yellow, game is over, speed and starting angle of red smileys should be random. I control the yellow smiley with arrow keys. The biggest problems I have: creating multiple red smileys and reflecting the red smileys from the boundary with the angle they came. I dont know how I can give a starting angle to a red smiley and bouncing it with the angle it came. I would be glad for any tips! Mycanvas size is 700x700 in the html file.

My js source code :

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Object containing some global Smiley properties.
var SmileyApp = {
   radius: 15,
   xspeed: 0,
   yspeed: 0,
   xpos:200,  // x-position of smiley
   ypos: 200  // y-position of smiley
};

var SmileyRed = {
   radius: 15,
   xspeed: 0,
   yspeed: 0,
   xpos:350,  // x-position of smiley
   ypos: 65  // y-position of smiley
};
function drawBigCircle() {
 var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
      var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
      var radiusBig = 300;

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radiusBig, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
//      context.fillStyle = 'green';
//      context.fill();
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;
 //     context.strokeStyle = '#003300'; // green
      ctx.stroke();
}

function lineDistance( positionx, positiony )
{
  var xs = 0;
  var ys = 0;

  xs = positionx - 350;
  xs = xs * xs;

  ys = positiony - 350;
  ys = ys * ys;

  return Math.sqrt( xs + ys );
}
function drawSmiley(x,y,r) {
   // outer border
   ctx.lineWidth = 3;
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(x,y,r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  //red ctx.fillStyle="rgba(255,0,0, 0.5)";
   ctx.fillStyle="rgba(255,255,0, 0.5)";
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.stroke();

   // mouth
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(x+0.7*r, y);
   ctx.arc(x,y,0.7*r, 0, Math.PI, false);

   // eyes
   var reye = r/10;
   var f = 0.4;
   ctx.moveTo(x+f*r, y-f*r);
   ctx.arc(x+f*r-reye, y-f*r, reye, 0, 2*Math.PI);
   ctx.moveTo(x-f*r, y-f*r);
   ctx.arc(x-f*r+reye, y-f*r, reye, -Math.PI, Math.PI);

   // nose
   ctx.moveTo(x,y);
   ctx.lineTo(x, y-r/2);
   ctx.lineWidth = 1;
   ctx.stroke();
}

function drawSmileyRed(x,y,r) {
   // outer border
   ctx.lineWidth = 3;
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(x,y,r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  //red 
  ctx.fillStyle="rgba(255,0,0, 0.5)";
  //yellow ctx.fillStyle="rgba(255,255,0, 0.5)";
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.stroke();

   // mouth
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(x+0.4*r, y+10);
   ctx.arc(x,y+10,0.4*r, 0, Math.PI, true);

   // eyes
   var reye = r/10;
   var f = 0.4;
   ctx.moveTo(x+f*r, y-f*r);
   ctx.arc(x+f*r-reye, y-f*r, reye, 0, 2*Math.PI);
   ctx.moveTo(x-f*r, y-f*r);
   ctx.arc(x-f*r+reye, y-f*r, reye, -Math.PI, Math.PI);

   // nose
   ctx.moveTo(x,y);
   ctx.lineTo(x, y-r/2);
   ctx.lineWidth = 1;
   ctx.stroke();
}


// --- Animation of smiley moving with constant speed and bounce back at edges of canvas ---
var tprev = 0;   // this is used to calculate the time step between two successive calls of run
function run(t) {
   requestAnimationFrame(run);
   if (t === undefined) {
      t=0;
   }
   var h = t - tprev;   // time step 
   tprev = t;

   SmileyApp.xpos += SmileyApp.xspeed * h/1000;  // update position according to constant speed
   SmileyApp.ypos += SmileyApp.yspeed * h/1000;  // update position according to constant speed
   // change speed direction if smiley hits canvas edges
   if (lineDistance(SmileyApp.xpos, SmileyApp.ypos) + SmileyApp.radius > 300) {
     alert("Game Over");
   }

   // redraw smiley at new position
   ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.height, canvas.width);
   drawBigCircle();
   drawSmiley(SmileyApp.xpos, SmileyApp.ypos, SmileyApp.radius);
   drawSmileyRed(SmileyRed.xpos, SmileyRed.ypos, SmileyRed.radius);
}

run();     

// --- Control smiley motion with left/right arrow keys                        
function arrowkeyCB(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

   if (event.keyCode === 37) { // left arrow
      SmileyApp.xspeed = -100; 
      SmileyApp.yspeed = 0;
   } else if (event.keyCode === 39) { // right arrow
      SmileyApp.xspeed = 100; 
      SmileyApp.yspeed = 0;
   } else if (event.keyCode === 38) { // up arrow
      SmileyApp.yspeed = -100;
      SmileyApp.xspeed = 0;   
   } else if (event.keyCode === 40) { // right arrow
      SmileyApp.yspeed = 100; 
      SmileyApp.xspeed = 0;
   }
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', arrowkeyCB, true);
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/X7gz7/

Comment: Can you setup a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @Rob Sure : http://jsfiddle.net/X7gz7/

Answer (score 0):

you need to find out line that is tangent/perpendicular to the point of collision. Then Subtract the angle formed by intersection of tangent line and radius line from 180 deg to find a new angle.

I'll post image explaining more later.